# Writing an instance of the form `(forall a . Class a => Class (f a)) => Class (Type f)`

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I perform default resolution in one of my programs by performing a natural transformation from `MyType Maybe` to `MyType Identity`. I want to derive a `ToJSON` instance for these types. I know that `Maybe` and `Identity` have instances `ToJSON a => ToJSON (Maybe a)` and `ToJSON a => ToJSON (Identity a)`.

I would like to declare an instance of the following form:

```
instance (forall a . ToJSON a => ToJSON (f a)) => ToJSON (MyType f)
```

This seems like a reasonable request to put forth to the type system. I want to demonstrate a `ToJSON` instance for `MyType f`, *provided* that I can always get a `ToJSON (f a)` for every `ToJSON a`. In logical notation, this is like saying that I can demonstrate *(P(a) ⇒ P(f(a))) ⇒ P(h(f))* for some property *P*. This seems well formed to me.

Unfortunately, I get the following error with the syntax as is:

```
• Illegal polymorphic type: forall a. ToJSON a => ToJSON (f a)
  A constraint must be a monotype
• In the context: (forall a. ToJSON a => ToJSON (f a))
  While checking an instance declaration
  In the instance declaration for ‘ToJSON (GpgParams f)’
```

It looks like the [QuantifiedConstraints](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/QuantifiedConstraints) proposal would provide this syntax, but it has not been implemented yet.

I can try to work around this constraint by implementing my own class `JSONable`.

```
class JSONable f where
  jsonize :: f a -> Value

  default jsonize :: (ToJSON a, ToJSON (f a)) => f a -> Value
  jsonize = toJSON
```

Unfortunately this means giving up all functions in the standard library that use require a `ToJSON` constraint.

As far as I can tell the best tradeoff in this case is to simply give up and write explicit instances for:

```
instance ToJSON (MyType Maybe)
instance ToJSON (MyType Identity)
```

Is it true that this is simply as powerful as the language gets? Is the desired instance simply ill-formed? Or is it in fact possible to declare such an instance in Haskell for an existing typeclass?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Until QuantifiedConstraints arrive, there is a standard solution to encode a constraint like `forall a. ToJSON a => ToJSON (f a)`, that seems like what you mentioned, but we don't have to give up functions that use a `ToJSON` constraint.

`forall a. ToJSON a => ToJSON (f a)` is a constraint on `f`: we can define that as a typeclass. Luckily, [*aeson* already has `ToJSON1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.3.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:ToJSON1).

```
class ToJSON1 f where  -- encoding of `forall a. ToJSON a => ToJSON (f a)`
  ...
```

And to use that class there is a function

```
toJSON1 :: (ToJSON1 f, ToJSON a) => f a -> Value
```

If any type `F` has an instance `ToJSON1 F`, then it is expected that its `ToJSON` instance is equivalent to

```
instance ToJSON a => ToJSON (F a) where
  toJSON = toJSON1
```

So that `ToJSON1 F` indeed encodes `forall a. ToJSON a => ToJSON1 (F a)`.

One thing that seems missing from *aeson* is a way to solve a `ToJSON (f a)` constraint given `ToJSON1 f` and `ToJSON a`, but you can also encode it using the following newtype (higher-kinded version of `Identity`):

```
newtype Id1 f a = Id1 { unId1 :: f a }

instance (ToJSON1 f, ToJSON a) => ToJSON (Id1 f a) where
  toJSON = toJSON1 . unId1
```

Then to define `ToJSON (MyType f)`, we can first apply `coerce :: MyType f -> MyType (Id1 f)`.

```
import Data.Coerce

instance ToJSON1 f => ToJSON (MyType f) where
  toJSON = (...) . (coerce :: MyType f -> MyType (Id1 f))
    {- in "(...)" we can use functions that require "ToJSON (Id1 f a)", which is informally equivalent to "ToJSON (f a)" -}
```

Comment: Great answer. However there is a typo in the type of `toJSON1`, should be `(ToJSON1 f, ToJSON a) => f a -> Value` (`f` is missing in the function argument)

Comment: This works great. I put `deriving (Generic1, ToJSON1)` on `Id1`, and from there it was easy to define a `generic1ToJSON` function analogous to Aeson's `genericToJSON`. Thank you!